# Highlighting a text from string by using sub-string method

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs, html

I have a string which you can is like:

> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged

Now, in this string, I do have an json object in which from back-end all the start and end offsets of string which I have to highlight.

Now, for highlighting I am using following logic:

```
$scope.highlightHTML = function(content, startoffset, endoffset) {
  var className = 'mark';
  console.log(content.substring(startoffset, endoffset));
  return content.replace(content.substring(startoffset, endoffset), '<span class="' + className + '">$&</span>');
}
```

Here content is the given string and start and end are the endoffsets of the highlighting string.

Now, while calling this:

```
jsonDataArray.forEach(function(item) {
  responseData = $scope.highlightHTML(responseData, item.startOffset, item.endOffset, item.color);
});
$rootScope.data.htmlDocument = responseData.replace(/\n/g, "</br>");
```

Here consider responseData is the string which I provided in the question. From this I am calling the highlighthtml function.

Here the problem is that I am replacing the string with the span tags. Now what happens in loop is that when first lets say in array first value to highlight is `the printing and typesetting industry.` . So, offsets of this I get from the backend. Now, it will highlight that by replacing with the spans.

Now, when in array for second value, let's say `a galley of type and scrambled it`  I get offsets but when it goes in highlight function then it is not getting the exact string because we have changed that string just by adding the span so now the offsets are changed for that string. So, because of this I am not able to highlight the proper words.

Comment: Is this thing doable ?

Comment: Yes it's doable in many ways, one of it is to update the offset indexes by adding the extra length for the spans.

Comment: @chŝdk But In loop every time it is going to add that may spans 5 or 6 then ?

Comment: Yes you will need to update the length proportionnally to your loop index.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Okay sorry for this

Answer (score 3):

You could go through you replacements from back to front by using a reversed loop to ensure the offsets of the elements, which aren't precessed yet aren't changed in the loop.

I added the sorting method as well, if you aren't sure if your data is in the correct order.

```js
$scope.highlightHTML = function(content, startoffset, endoffset) {
  var className = 'mark';
  console.log(content.substring(startoffset, endoffset));
  return content.replace(content.substring(startoffset, endoffset), '<span class="' + className + '">$&</span>');
}

//Only if you don't know if they are in the correct order:
jsonDataArray = jsonDataArray.sort((a, b) => a.startOffset - b.startOffset);

for (var i = jsonDataArray.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  const item = jsonDataArray[i];
  responseData = $scope.highlightHTML(responseData, item.startOffset, item.endOffset, item.color);
};
$rootScope.data.htmlDocument = responseData.replace(/\n/g, "</br>");
```

Comment: Let me check once this

Comment: `some errors` is not very helpful. Did you try sorting them?

Comment: No When I run this snippet that time

Comment: This snippet can't work. I just used it for syntax highlighting

Comment: Sorry, there was really an error in the second to last line `});` has to be `};`. I editet it

Comment: If you are sure the highlights don't overlap, `startOffeset` is all you need to sort for

Comment: Overlapping may be there

Comment: Actually That is what I was going to tell you that this may happen like one thing which we highlighted can come in another thing in middle

Comment: Where do I add $scope.highlightHTML = $scope.highlightHTML.sort((a, b) => a.startOffset - b.startOffset); this ?

Comment: Just before you iterate through your json

Comment: $scope.highlightHTML = $scope.highlightHTML.sort((a, b) => a.startOffset - b.startOffset);
                for (var i = jsonDataArray.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                  const item = jsonDataArray[i];
                  responseData = $scope.highlightHTML(responseData, item.startOffset, item.endOffset, item.color);
                };   It is saying sort is not a function.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167411/discussion-between-sebastian-speitel-and-ganeshk).

Comment: Now , In this you used the for loop so that it will start highlighting from last but what if the first one which we want to highlight is present at the last word. then again it is creating the problems

Comment: Hey, Your soultion is working perfectly fine.But One problem is there is the first word which we want to highlight is present at end only then it will change the offsets .

Comment: What can be the solution for this ?

Comment: Hey, DO you have any solution for the overlapping on one another ? If any then it would be really helpful for me . I am stuck on that point.

Answer (score 1):

You can update the `offsets` by adding the extra `length` for the spans text added, in your loop like this:

```
var length = '<span class="mark"></span>'.length:
jsonDataArray.forEach(function(item, index) {
    responseData = $scope.highlightHTML(responseData, item.startOffset + (index * length), item.endOffset + (index * length), item.color);
});
$rootScope.data.htmlDocument = responseData.replace(/\n/g, "</br>");
```

So here in each iteration, you will be incrementing both offsets with `(index *length)`, so for the first iteration you won't update them because `index`is `0`, then you will increment it by `1*length` and so on.

Comment: Let me please check this If this works or not. Thanks for replying

Comment: @ganeshk Ok, yes of course, take your time to test this.

Comment: I do have one question Like If every time it is going to add some spans in that then How we will take care of this ?

Comment: @ganeshk Like I said it will update according to loop `index`, in the `(index*length)` expression.

Comment: Okay Let me check this And I immediately revert you back.

Comment: I Think do we need to add condition there for first if(index ==0) then do not add that length ?

Comment: Got it it will be multiplied by zero

Comment: @ganeshk It's already checked in , have you seen the note under the code, *so for the first iteration you won't update them because `index`is `0`*.

Comment: Actually it is still not giving me the exact output like it is not taking the exact string

Comment: Is it may be because of the </br> tag ?

Comment: They are not in the order thats why may be this is not giving the proper result

Comment: In document they are not in the order . This is the problem

Comment: Show us your josn input as well?! But normally it should work even if they aren't ordered.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167405/discussion-between-ganeshk-and-chsdk).

Comment: No, I meant the sentence order in the string.

Comment: If highlighting array may have a text which is at index 0, but that text may be present at the end of the document .

Comment: Sorry for the late reply . can you please check this once again ? It will be really helpful

Comment: Hey, I tried with your solution, Here one problem is that if the one value is present in another I mean overlapping then it is giving problem

Comment: One more thing,  '<span class="mark"></span>' here class mark will be different on each time