# Compare the data which is present in the array with other array elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, arrays, angularjs

I am new to `angularjs and javascript`. Here, I have an array of objects like -->

```
[{
        annotationType: "Full Name:"
        endOffset: "17"
        startOffset: "0",
        type: "FullName"
        value: "Abc"
    },
    {
        annotationType: "Email:"
        endOffset: "44"
        startOffset: "26",
        type: "email"
        value: "zazazbc"
    },
    {
        annotationType: "Telephone:"
        endOffset: "63"
        startOffset: "53",
        type: "TelephoneNumber"
        value: "123444455"
    },
    {
        annotationType: "Skill Set:"
        endOffset: "920"
        startOffset: "363",
        type: "skillset"
        value: "Summary Of Skills : Total 4+ years of experience in Web Applications and web Sites "
    },

   {
        annotationType: "Total Experience::"
        endOffset: "398"
        startOffset: "390",
        type: "TotalExperiece"
        value: "4+ years"
    },
]
```

Now, In this array, I have start offsets and endoffsets . Now, I actually highlighting the data . Now, Here what is happening one value is present in another value then while highlighting css are getting override. So, I want to get to know whether the offsets are present in between another values,

Here for example annotation type total experience is present in the skillset. Because Skillset is 363 to 920 and totalExperience is 390 to 398. So, Here its giving issues. So, I want to have an array where the overlapping is happend. So, I want to compare 1st array value with all other and like wise , so every value should compare with other values.

How can I do this ? can any one help me with this ?

```
var check_If_One_Is_Present_In_Another = function (jsonDataArray) {
          for (var i = 1; i < jsonDataArray.length; i++) {
            if ((jsonDataArray[i].startOffset <= jsonDataArray[0].startOffset && jsonDataArray[i].endOffset <= jsonDataArray[0].endOffset && jsonDataArray[0].startOffset < jsonDataArray[i].endOffset) ||
              (jsonDataArray[0].startOffset <= jsonDataArray[i].startOffset && jsonDataArray[0].endOffset <= jsonDataArray[i].endOffset && jsonDataArray[i].startOffset < jsonDataArray[0].endOffset) ||
              (jsonDataArray[i].startOffset <= jsonDataArray[0].startOffset && jsonDataArray[0].endOffset <= jsonDataArray[i].endOffset && jsonDataArray[0].startOffset < jsonDataArray[0].endOffset) ||
              (jsonDataArray[0].startOffset <= jsonDataArray[i].startOffset && jsonDataArray[i].endOffset <= jsonDataArray[0].endOffset && jsonDataArray[i].startOffset < jsonDataArray[i].endOffset)) {

                console.log("in this ===>", jsonDataArray[i].type);
            }
          }
```

This is for checking if the one value is half present in another. also

Comment: Please try and get back if you have any stuck

Comment: Actually I tried this using the for loops and then taking the values. But not able to do.

Comment: Post the loop that you have done and post a sample output

Comment: Please check the tried version

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: The output array should have the total experience because it is present in between the skill sets offsets.

Comment: Actually, I am doing this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49445239/highlighting-a-text-from-string-by-using-sub-string-method  second solution. But because of the overlapping issue, this is not happening.

Comment: Can you please update the question with your expected output?